# Exception Handling in Async Gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I have a gateway implementation as below. I have defined an error-channel in the gateway to trap any exception in the entire SI flow. The outputChannel sends the response back out of the gateway. As you can see there are 3 parallel flows in the system created using splitter and router.

In ErrorHandlingService, I set the appropriate error codes and send the message back to the aggregateDSLResponseChannel so that the entire flow completes smoothly. I need an implementation where entire flow ends in DSLFlowEndService even when there is an exception and then return response back to the caller by settings appropriate response object.The reason is if there was a request to connect to say WLDP and IRIS and say WLDP flow failed but IRIS succeeds, I don't want to send complete response as failure. Instead I would send an appropriate message back to the caller mentioning partial success (with details of what failed and succeeded)

To test, I introduced an exception in WLDPFlowEndService. The exception comes to error channel and then message also travels back to aggregateDSLResponseChannel and then to DSLFlowEndService. However the response is not sent back to the caller outside gateway. Basically Spring integration flow never completes and times out after 30 secs as configured. Below is the warning that comes in the logs:

```
15:13:23.271 [dslParallelExecutor-2] WARN  org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel {} - Reply message being sent, but the receiving thread has already received a reply:[Payload=DSLResponseVO 
15:13:23.271 [dslParallelExecutor-2] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel {} - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'outputChannel', message: [Payload=DSLResponseVO
```

**Updated configuration- one that works (super thanks to Gary) **:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

<int:channel id="inputChannel"></int:channel>

<int:channel id="outputChannel"></int:channel>

<int:channel id="dslFlowInitiatorOutputChannel"/>

<int:channel id="routingChannel"/>

<int:channel id="wldpInputChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="wldpParallelExecutor" />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="lcInputChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="lcParallelExecutor" />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="irisInputChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="irisParallelExecutor" />
</int:channel>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="aggregateDSLResponseChannel"></int:publish-subscribe-channel>

<int:channel id="aggregateDSLOutputChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="dslParallelExecutor" />
</int:channel>

<!-- all thread pools to execute tasks in parallel -->
<task:executor id="dslParallelExecutor" pool-size="50" />
<task:executor id="wldpParallelExecutor" pool-size="25" />
<task:executor id="lcParallelExecutor" pool-size="25" />
<task:executor id="irisParallelExecutor" pool-size="25" />

<int:gateway id="dslServiceFacade" service-interface="com.mycompany.tss.ls.dsl.gateway.IDSLServiceFacade"  
    default-request-channel="inputChannel" default-reply-channel="outputChannel" error-channel="gatewayErrorChannel" async-executor="dslParallelExecutor">
    <int:method name="invoke" request-channel="inputChannel" request-timeout="5000" reply-timeout="3000000"/>
</int:gateway>

<int:service-activator input-channel="inputChannel"
    output-channel="dslFlowInitiatorOutputChannel" ref="dslFlowInitiatorService"
    method="invoke" id="dslFlowInitiator" />

<bean id="dslFlowInitiatorService" class="com.mycompany.tss.ls.dsl.service.DSLFlowInitiatorService" />

<int:splitter id="systemSplitter" input-channel="dslFlowInitiatorOutputChannel" method="split"
                output-channel="routingChannel" ref="systemMessageSplitter">
</int:splitter>

<bean id="systemMessageSplitter" class="com.mycompany.tss.ls.dsl.splitter.SystemMessageSplitter"/>

<int:router id="systemRouter" input-channel="routingChannel" default-output-channel="nullChannel" 
    expression="headers.get('systemId')">
    <int:mapping value="WLDP" channel="wldpInputChannel" />
    <int:mapping value="LC" channel="lcInputChannel" />
    <int:mapping value="IRIS" channel="irisInputChannel" />
</int:router>

<int:aggregator id="dslResponseAggregator" input-channel="aggregateDSLResponseChannel" output-channel="aggregateDSLOutputChannel"
    message-store="dslResponseMessageStore" correlation-strategy-expression="headers['requestId']" 
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true">
</int:aggregator>

<int:service-activator input-channel="aggregateDSLOutputChannel"
    output-channel="outputChannel" ref="dslFlowEndService"
    method="invoke" id="dslFlowEndActivator" />

<bean id="dslFlowEndService" class="com.mycompany.tss.ls.dsl.service.DSLFlowEndService" />

<bean id="dslResponseMessageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore" />

<bean id="dslResponseMessageStoreReaper" class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
    <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="dslResponseMessageStore" />
    <property name="timeout" value="4000" />
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="dslResponseMessageStoreReaper" method="run" fixed-rate="10000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<int:wire-tap pattern="*Channel" order="3" channel="wiretap"/>
<int:message-history/>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="wiretap" level="DEBUG"/>


<!-- Error handling Service Activator to log exceptions and send the response -->
<int:service-activator id="errorHandlingServiceActivator" input-channel="gatewayErrorChannel"
    method="invoke" output-channel="aggregateDSLResponseChannel" ref="errorHandlingService">
</int:service-activator>

<!-- Error Handling Service class -->
<bean id="errorHandlingService" class="com.mycompany.tss.ls.dsl.service.ErrorHandlingService" />
<bean id="wldpErrorHandlingService" class="com.mycompany.tss.ls.dsl.service.ErrorHandlingService" />
<bean id="irisErrorHandlingService" class="com.mycompany.tss.ls.dsl.service.ErrorHandlingService" />

<int:channel id="wldpStartChannel"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="irisStartChannel"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="wldpErrorChannel"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="irisErrorChannel"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="wldpOutputChannel"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="irisOutputChannel"></int:channel>

<int:service-activator id="midFlowWLDPActivator" input-channel="wldpInputChannel" 
    ref="midFlowWLDPGateway" output-channel="aggregateDSLResponseChannel"/>

<int:service-activator id="midFlowIRISActivator" input-channel="irisInputChannel" 
    ref="midFlowIRISGateway" output-channel="aggregateDSLResponseChannel"/>

<int:gateway id="midFlowWLDPGateway" default-request-channel="wldpStartChannel" 
    service-interface="com.mycompany.tss.ls.dsl.gateway.IDSLWLDPFacade" error-channel="wldpErrorChannel" 
/>


<int:gateway id="midFlowIRISGateway" default-request-channel="irisStartChannel" 
    service-interface="com.mycompany.tss.ls.dsl.gateway.IDSLIRISFacade" error-channel="irisErrorChannel" 
/>


<int:service-activator id="errorHandlingWLDPServiceActivator" input-channel="wldpErrorChannel"
    method="invoke" ref="wldpErrorHandlingService">
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator id="errorHandlingIRISServiceActivator" input-channel="irisErrorChannel"
    method="invoke" ref="irisErrorHandlingService">
</int:service-activator>

<!-- Responsible for closing all the activities related to WLDP before sending response -->
<int:service-activator id="wldpFlowEndServiceActivator" input-channel="wldpStartChannel"
    method="invoke" ref="wldpFlowEndService">
</int:service-activator>

<bean id="wldpFlowEndService" class="com.mycompany.tss.ls.dsl.service.wldp.WLDPFlowEndService" />

<!-- Responsible for closing all the activities related to IRIS before sending response -->
<int:service-activator id="irisFlowEndServiceActivator" input-channel="irisStartChannel"
    method="invoke">
</int:service-activator>


<bean id="irisFlowEndService" class="com.mycompany.tss.ls.dsl.service.iris.IrisFlowEndService" />
```

**ErrorHandlingService:**

public class ErrorHandlingService {

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorHandlingService.class);

public Message<DSLResponseVO> invoke(Message<?> requestMessage) {

    Object exception = requestMessage.getPayload();
    if(exception instanceof MessagingException){
        DSLResponseVO responseVO = new DSLResponseVO();
        logger.error("Exception has occurred: {}", ((MessagingException)exception).getMessage());
        logger.error("Exception Stacktrace is: ", exception);
        responseVO.setRequestId((String)((MessagingException)exception).getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get("requestId"));
        responseVO.setSystemId((String)((MessagingException)exception).getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get("systemId"));
        responseVO.setErrorCode(DSLErrorConstants.FAILURE_CODE);
        responseVO.setErrorMessage(DSLErrorConstants.FAILURE_DESC);

        Message<DSLResponseVO> failedMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(responseVO)
                //.copyHeadersIfAbsent(((MessagingException)exception).getFailedMessage().getHeaders())
                .setHeaderIfAbsent("requestId", (String)((MessagingException)exception).getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get("requestId"))
                .setHeaderIfAbsent("systemId", (String)((MessagingException)exception).getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get("systemId"))
                .setHeaderIfAbsent(MessageHeaders.SEQUENCE_NUMBER, (Integer)((MessagingException)exception).getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get(MessageHeaders.SEQUENCE_NUMBER))
                .setHeaderIfAbsent(MessageHeaders.SEQUENCE_SIZE, (Integer)((MessagingException)exception).getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get(MessageHeaders.SEQUENCE_SIZE))
                .setHeaderIfAbsent(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, ((MessagingException)exception).getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL))
                .build();

        return failedMessage;
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send multiple replies to the gateway; you need to aggregate the results (or failures) into a single reply message.

Each subflow needs to send the result, or error to and aggregator.

You need an error flow on each subflow. If you use a queue channel instead of executor channel, you can put an error-channel on the poller.

When using executor channel you need a mid-flow gateway to add an error flow (service activator that references a `<gateway/>`).

Comment: Thanks Gary for your response. I am actually creating a response from error handling flow and then sending it back to the aggregator. Do you see any issue with this? As message does get aggregated into single message but there is a warning and response never gets written out.. If using poller on the subflow with error channel and the task executor is the right way, I can try that... I am hoping that when exception is thrown in any component under sub flow it would goto sub flow poller error channel and not to the error channel of the gateway. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think that your suggested approach of queue channel with poller for every sub flow is a better approach.

Comment: You have to be careful when routing errors to an aggregator; there have been a number of questions about this here. If you can't find one where I have answered, let me know and I'll try to find one. The bottom line is the correlation headers are not in the `ErrorMessage`, they are in the `failedMessage` property of the error message payload. On your error flow, you need to transform to the failed message (or otherwise promote the headers) before sending the error to the aggregator.

Comment: Gary, I am getting the headers from the failed message and creating a new payload. It is also getting aggregated properly. Only issue is it is not able to send the response back. I will try the other option that you mentioned of having error handling for each subflow and see if it works...

Comment: The mechanism by which you get the error message to the error flow shouldn't make any difference. DEBUG logging and following the messages should show what's going on. If you can't figure it out, edit the question with your current config and paste the logs someplace like a github gist or pastebin.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your help so far. I have updated the complete configuration and the ErrorHandlerService code. Also pasted the logs at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e61aef85f3656a998fc . Please suggest what could be going wrong here.

Comment: In parallel, I referred to your similar advise of creating mid flow gateway as described here http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/129136-error-channel-gateway-problem . And was trying to create something similar. The message is getting aggregated now but it is losing the replyChannel. I think because of the extra gateway I added. Now looking at way to get the replyChannel of the original gateway into the headers back.

Comment: You can't route directly to the aggregator from the gateway subflow; your error flow needs to return the error result to the gateway and so it can be properly routed.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your help so far. I have changed the configuration to have mid flow gateway now. However I am back to square one. The message is getting aggregated properly but the replyChannel and errorChannel headers are lost after aggregation and results in hannelResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available. Not able to really make out whats going wrong. It would be great if you could review the Update Configuration above and the logs at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d8c047e1e7fc2da9d83c . If you can provide some example to refer, it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Please read my previous comment; you are sending directly to the `aggregateDSLResponseChannel` from the subflow via a bridge. Instead, simply remove the `output-channel` from the `wldpFlowEndServiceActivator`. Then, the reply will go back to the mid-flow gateway and the result will then be properly routed to the aggregator with the correct headers. Do the same for each service activator (normal and error).

Comment: Thanks Gary, it worked finally. This would have not been possible without all your help. Really appreciate your support.